# Facebook share information on site

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-social-plugins

I'm working on a site, where users answer a question, and selects some informations by checkboxes.

Then I'd like to add the wellknown function, where you click "Share on Facebook", and the anwer and selected information is posted on Facebook like:

"Hi. I answered the question {question} and I think the right answer is {answer}. Try it yourself on url.com to win a great price" ... or something...

What is this called? I looked into Facebook Developer-site, but I couldn't find it...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/